# Show and hide different options when an id is selected

Tags: jquery, select, switch-statement, toggle

I am trying to show different options when the user selects `#im-buying` or `#im-renting`.

This is how my code is set up at the moment, I'm current hiding the `.renting` class until the user switches the option to `#im-buying`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#im-buying').change(function() {
    $('.renting').hide();
    $('.buying').show();
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#im-renting').change(function() {
    $('.buying').hide();
    $('.renting').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option id="im-buying" value="BUY A PROPERTY">Buy a property</option>
  <option id="im-renting" value="RENT A PROPERTY">Rent a property</option>
</select>


<h4>
  <strong>MIN PRICE:</strong>
</h4>
<select class="buying">
  <option value="not specific">Not Specific</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£40,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£50,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£60,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£70,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£80,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£90,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£100,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£110,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£120,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£130,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£140,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£150,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£200,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£300,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£400,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£500,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£600,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£700,000+</option>
</select>

<select class="renting">
  <option value="not specific">Not Specific</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£250</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£450</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£600</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£700</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£800</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£1000</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£1100</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£1200</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£1400</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you're targeting the `option` from the `select`. You have to target the `select` element when using `change()`. This can also be resumed to one `change()` method and by using `toggle()` method:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#main_select').change(function() {
    $('.renting').toggle($(this).val() == 'RENT A PROPERTY');
    $('.buying').toggle($(this).val() == 'BUY A PROPERTY');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="main_select">
              <option selected disabled>Select an option</option>
              <option id="im-buying" value="BUY A PROPERTY">Buy a property</option>
              <option id="im-renting" value="RENT A PROPERTY">Rent a property</option>
          </select>


<h4><strong>MIN PRICE:</strong></h4>
<select class="buying">
            <option value="not specific">Not Specific buying</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£40,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£50,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£60,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£70,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£80,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£90,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£100,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£110,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£120,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£130,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£140,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£150,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£200,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£300,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£400,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£500,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£600,000</option>
            <option value="MIN PRICE">£700,000+</option>
          </select>

<select class="renting">
            <option value="not specific">Not Specific renting</option>
            <option value="MAX PRICE">£250</option>
            <option value="MAX PRICE">£450</option>
            <option value="MAX PRICE">£600</option>
            <option value="MAX PRICE">£700</option>
            <option value="MAX PRICE">£800</option>
            <option value="MAX PRICE">£1000</option>
            <option value="MAX PRICE">£1100</option>
            <option value="MAX PRICE">£1200</option>
            <option value="MAX PRICE">£1400</option>
          </select>
```

Comment: ahhh i see now thats so much easier than i thought, thank you so much makes so much sense now :) really appreicate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you're hooking the `change` event on the `option` elements, when instead it should be placed on the `select` itself. From there you can check the `value` property which was chosen and `toggle()` the appropriate `select`.

Also note that you only need to create one document.ready handler; all code to be executed once the DOM has loaded can then be placed in that. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#type').change(function() {
    $('.renting').toggle(this.value == 'rent');
    $('.buying').toggle(this.value == 'buy');
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type">
  <option value="buy">Buy a property</option>
  <option value="rent">Rent a property</option>
</select>

<h4>
  <strong>MIN PRICE:</strong>
</h4>
<select class="buying">
  <option value="not specific">Not Specific</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£40,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£50,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£60,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£70,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£80,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£90,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£100,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£110,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£120,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£130,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£140,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£150,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£200,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£300,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£400,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£500,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£600,000</option>
  <option value="MIN PRICE">£700,000+</option>
</select>

<select class="renting">
  <option value="not specific">Not Specific</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£250</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£450</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£600</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£700</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£800</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£1000</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£1100</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£1200</option>
  <option value="MAX PRICE">£1400</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you also :) both seem to be perfect ways to do this problem i really appreciate it Rory :)

Comment: @Mayo, ok, to be fair, I think this answer should be accepted, as it was first and had the best logic in it. Indeed I edited a bit my answer to use toggle instead of `if...else`, but that does not mean I didn't knew about the `toggle()`. If you are not convinced to accept it there is a way, you should accept the answer you used in your code.